# Setting up a vpn and IIS IP address restrictions

Tags: iis, vpn, iis-7.5

I'm trying to get a VPN set up with internal access only sites.

I have set up a VPN on a windows server (single VPS server), and I can connect from a remote computer and I get an IP assigned correctly (from 192.168.1.1 - 255)

Next I configured IIS (running on the same machine) IP Address and Domain Restrictions to only allow only IP address range 192.168.1.0 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0

When I connect to the VPN with "Use Default Gateway on Remote Network" (so that requests must go through the vpn), I get a 403 from the internal sites.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

So after figuring out that I can't ping the server's internal ip from the client and vice versa, and seeing [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/227636/cant-ping-a-server-over-vpn) question, I added the LAN routing service to the server, which allowed pinging. I then added a route as per [this](https://superuser.com/questions/12022/how-can-i-make-the-windows-vpn-route-selective-traffic-by-destination-network) question, and now I can connect to sites with restricted IPs.